# Unity Prefab that i placed doesn't move

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to move Prefab object so I write this code but when I place prefab on scene, it doesn't move. Only prefab in files x is changing.

What should I have to do? (This is 2D game.)

```
public IEnumerator IfButtonTouched() {

  Debug.Log("isWorking?");
  while (timer <= seconds) {

    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    obstacle.transform.Translate((new Vector3( - 1, 0, 0)) * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    Debug.Log("pleaseWork");
    yield
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: You only told it to move on the x axis. It cant do miracles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access to a prefab with the name of the GameObject.

You cant `Instantiate(obstacle, transform.position, quaternion.identity)` and then

```
obstacle.transform.Translate
```

Of course you will move the prefab and not the actual object!

You should do this way

```
GameObject obstacleSpawned = Instantiate(obstacle, transform.position, Quaternion.Identity) as GameObject;
```

And then you can access to `obstacleSpawned` and move it!

Comment: Thank you for helping me!! I'll gonna try it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Soo if it worked then accept the answer so it will be useful for others :)